# Finding a file in Vb.net and UnauthorizedAccessException problems

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to search a drive letter (C drive) for a file in Vb.Net 2010. After I find the file path I want to run the executable. This is the code I am trying to use to find the file:

```
path = Convert.ToString(IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "wswc.exe", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

This throws an UnauthorizedAccessException when my code tries to search a recycle bin (or some other file that I don't have access to) and I have searched the internet and people have suggested to use Try...Catch...End Try but this will not work for me since I am not using a loop and I don't know how to change my code to function as a loop. I have seen where is was suggested to  use the GetAccessControl method to test for permissions before searching the directory but I was not sure how use use it with my current code.

I have not been able to test the Convert.ToString(...) because of the UnauthorizedAccessException so if there is something wrong with this or any of the rest of the code please let me know.

I am fairly new to VB.Net so try to keep your explanation simple.

Thank you.

Comment: That code will always take a nose dive on c:\system volume information.  The directory where restore points are stored.  Even having admin access doesn't let you look into it.  You will have to iterate the directories one at a time, Directory.GetDirectories().

Comment: How would I do that exactly? What is it I would do with Directory.GetDirectories()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to see this thread

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/255be857-9d1e-4c80-9ae2-5c8b48697943/

Regards.

Comment: I have adapted the code at the link and it mostly works. I now get an UnauthorizedAccessException error for Documents and Settings (I'm using windows 7) I know I could add another ElseIf statement to exclude that location but I would like to have the program test the location and then if access is denied skip, else search the directory. This program is going to be used on Windows 7 and Windows XP and I don't want skip a directory that I might be able to access in another version of windows.

Comment: Hello, if you intend to use the same type of code you can think of to identify which operating system and installed it, and therefore whether or not to search a directory that does not have problems with XP, while windows7 can give you. Regards

Comment: I figured out how to adapt the code to search programmatically and skip files that it cannot access. Too bad it won't let me search the Program Files folder from the C drive.

Comment: Since I can't edit my comment above:I started the search from the Program Files folder to get around this. I think this will work for now. I'll probably try to start searches inside the directories that I don't have access to but would likely contain the file I am searching for.

Comment: the fact that the subsequent product versions to Windows XP, have been included rights of access, one of them and the folder ProgramFiles in Windows 7, which is not present on Windows XP, you can still groped for what they do and run your application by starting with administrator rights.Regards

Answer (score 2):

I originally asked this question and I have code that now searches all of the directories for a file. I feel obligated to post the actual code so that someone with a similar problem can use mine. I'm using a different account because I can't seem to log in to the one I created. You need four listboxes to run this code.

```
    'Run the file if found
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String

    'Search for a specified file
    Start_Search(ListBox1)

    For k = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        Try
            ListBox2.SelectedIndex = k
            path = ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
    Quit()

End Sub

    'Set the root of your search
    Private Sub Start_Search(ByVal listbox1 As ListBox)
    Dim strroot As String
    strroot = "C:\"
    listbox1.Items.Add(strroot)
    Search(listbox1, ListBox2)
    End Sub

    'Search all directories and sub-directories in the search root(s)
    Private Sub Search(ByVal listbox1 As ListBox, ByVal listbox2 As ListBox)
    Dim listbox4 As New ListBox

    'Get all sub-directories of all items in your search root(s) (listbox1), 
    'clear listbox1, copy all sub-directories into listbox1 
    For j = 0 To listbox1.Items.Count - 1
        listbox1.SelectedIndex = j
        Try
            For Each strfolder As String In   My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
            listbox4.Items.Add(strfolder)
            Dim junk = listbox4.Items.Count - 1
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
    listbox1.Items.Clear()
    listbox1 = listbox4

    'every directory that throws an UnauthorizedAccessException is 
    'placed into listbox3. Then there is a recursive call on listbox3 
    '
    For i = 0 To listbox1.Items.Count - 1
        Try
            listbox1.SelectedIndex = i
    'You can place the file you are looking for in this line
            listbox2.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString & "\", "File to Find.exe", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            ListBox3.Items.Add(listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
        Catch ex1 As Exception
        End Try

    Next
    If listbox2.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Return
    ElseIf ListBox3.Items.Count >= 0 Then
        Search(ListBox3, listbox2)
    End If
    Return
End Sub
```

I hope this code can be of use to someone. It worked for me but there may be bugs in it. Thank you for your help Carmelo La Monica.

Comment: Hi Pulsar27, You're Welcome.Best Regards